# OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long python and odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

Actualmente estoy trabajando un proyecto con facturas electrónicas en odoo el cual su firma es xadesbes,el código que realiza la firma esta en java  ,Estoy utilizando la librería subprocess para ejecutar el comando java para que pueda realizar la firma Xml y funciona bien.

el codigo funciona un 98% con subprocess pero el problema aparece en el momento que el xml es muy muy largo superando los 4000 caracteres.

**He leído algunos pos que la forma de solucionar esto es cambiar arg_max  del kernel ,pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer esto esto es seguro?.**

**¿existe alguna otra forma de ejectuar este comando java para evitar este error?**

```
codigo subprocess:
    command = [
        "java",
        '-jar',
        "firmaXadesBes.jar",
        arg1,  # XML
        arg2,
        arg3
    ]
    subprocess.check_output(command)
```

**arg1 : es el xml en string si supera mas de 4000 caractere sale  el error.
arg:2 arhivo.12 seguridad en base64.
arg3:contraseña en base64.**

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, talvez pudiste encontrar alguna solución a este problema ? Muchas gracias